# How do you use param in Laravel view click event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

In Laravel Spark I'm just trying to add a param to the click event of the registration form.  The button out of the box:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="register" :disabled="registerForm.busy">
```

Everything I've found in regards using a param in the link is using href link, I cannot find anything regarding the click event of a button in the blade template ?

I've tried `@click.prevent="register/:param"`, `@click.prevent="register/{param}"`, I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think  `register` is a function in vuejs you have pass param as function param.

Comment: I guess this code is of vuejs not in laravel, change your tag

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** 
   @click.prevent="register(params)"